# Disable horizontal swipe on scene

Tags: react-native

I have a vertical `ScrollView` and a smaller horizontal `ScrollView` in a single scene.

The first time the scene is rendered it works fine, but the second time, when the user tries to scroll on the horizontal scroll, the whole scene is dragged with the following effect:

[image]

Is there a way to set the property `NavigatorIOS.interactivePopGestureEnabled` or to workaround this with the core `Navigator`?

I've already done the whole navigation using `Navigator`, and having to change to `NavigatorIOS` right now would be a huge pain.

Update: just tested this on Android and it has the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a custom animation scene config.

```js
const BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

const CustomSceneConfigNoSwipeGestures = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
  springTension:  100,
  springFriction: 1,
  gestures: {}
});

  pushScreen = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: 'My Screen',
      component: MyScreen,
      sceneConfig: CustomSceneConfigNoSwipeGestures,
    });
  }
```

The empty gestures: {} object overwrites the standard behaviour that would be applied from the Navigator.SceneConfigs objects.

Comment: Thanks, and you also gave me some insight and there are only some `SceneConfigs` that had this behavior. It was driving me insane. For example: `PushFromRight` doesn't have this gestures.